# Reduction of internal width

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain to me why I can not reduce the internal width of the borders to make the text more centralized? For some hours I can not find a solution. I am a beginner in this world and would like some help, please.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRVG6.png

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta name="keywords" content="piauí fábio abreu segurança eleições">
        <title>Fábio Abreu</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Fábio Abreu">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Fábio Abreu">
        <meta name="description" content="Site do deputado federal e secretário de segurança do estado do Piauí, Fábio Abreu.">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Site do deputado federal e secretário de segurança do estado do Piauí, Fábio Abreu.">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Site do deputado federal e secretário de segurança do estado do Piauí, Fábio Abreu."> 

        <meta property="og:image" content="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png">
        <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png">

        <meta property="og:image:width" content="600">

        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Fábio Abreu">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fabioabreupi.com.br/">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">

<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="vpi2ZdaYpPrfr3GiW3yekW5e5L4yLKfTfcU56OPrD8jGzbLTzDbW9jk89Lge96/mnQzU4zRCbJY2MuADwoWYIw==" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/site-dc393f9cdad26bd31342ace6c0e567e3893492c1ec06c16976bea61958ce06ad.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/default/css/main-5c3e617fe669fbfd1915fd6ba42ddae97daaf842e3037fde45d55bfdd0f7b4aa.css" />

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.fabioabreupi.com.br/">

<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/original_95e76849-329a-449b-8e1b-f118083035a4.png' /> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto Condensed:400,400i,700,700i' rel='stylesheet'>   <style>


            #TopMenu ul#menu-main li a,#TopMenu ul#menu-main li a span.caret{font-size:14px !important;text-transform:uppercase !important}
            #MainHeader{background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important}
            h3{font-size:15px !important;font-family:'Roboto Condensed' !important;font-weight:bold !important}

            footer#MainFooter{background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;border-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important}
    </style>

<style>#TopMenu{
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2722ad+28,ff3b21+100 */
background: #2722ad; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2722ad 28%, #ff3b21 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2722ad 28%,#ff3b21 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #2722ad 28%,#ff3b21 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2722ad', endColorstr='#ff3b21',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#menu-main{
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 9px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 9px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

#menu-main li:last-child{
  /*padding-left: 178px;*/
  margin-left: 376px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 1px; 
}

#menu-main li:last-child{
    /*background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 42px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    text-indent:-3.44px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    height:32px;
    line-height:32px;
    width:200px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}/*.classname:hover {
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;*/

    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius: 66px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:1px 22px;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}

#menu-main li:nth-last-child(2){
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu-main li:nth-last-child(3){
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu-main li:nth-last-child(4){
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu-main li:nth-last-child(5){
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#MainHeader{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px; 
}

#MainFooter{
 background-color: #00004d 
}

#GroupList1{
 background-color: #ffffff; 
 box-shadow: none;
}

#lws-homesection-title{
  text-align: center;
}

#GroupList2{
 display: none; 
}
.lws-homesection-body{
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 1.8;
}</style>
</head>

<body class="palette-red">


    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <header id="MainHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row vertical-align">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <div class="LogoArea">
                        <a href="/" id="BrandImage">
                            <img src="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png" alt="Fábio Abreu" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        </a>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div id="ContactsTop">


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<nav id="TopMenu" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn">
          <li><a href="/" target="">Início</a></li>
              <li><a href="/categories/noticias">NOTÍCIAS</a></li>

              <li><a href="/categories/fotos">FOTOS</a></li>

              <li><a href="/categories/projetos">PROJETOS</a></li>

              <li><a href="/biografia">BIOGRAFIA</a></li>

              <li><a href="www.whatsapp.com.br">ENTRE EM CONTATO</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="mySlide">
    <div style="width:100%;" id="bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" class="inner-content-slide carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000" data-pause="hover"><ol class="carousel-indicators"><li data-target="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li><li data-target="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li><li data-target="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li></ol><div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"><div class="item active"><div data-img-height="481" data-img-width="1000" class="item-img" role="img" aria-label="" style="height:500px;background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_f5a4a97f-204c-4538-bc79-d4bed4be75f3.jpeg);background-size:cover"></div></div><div class="item "><div data-img-height="480" data-img-width="1000" class="item-img" role="img" aria-label="" style="height:500px;background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_06fa6929-4e05-4d40-aebd-99233e3852d6.JPG);background-size:cover"></div></div><div class="item "><div data-img-height="488" data-img-width="1000" class="item-img" role="img" aria-label="" style="height:500px;background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_471118d4-7857-496c-b0db-21d5479de784.jpg);background-size:cover"></div></div></div><a class="left carousel-control" href="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" role="button" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-prev"></i><span class="sr-only">Anterior</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-next"></i><span class="sr-only">Próximo</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="marketing">
    <div class="container"><section data-section-area='V10'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='V10' data-section-id='c60fb099-5b76-4835-a254-f7ead8bde197'><div class='lws-homesection-text-image'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6'><img src='https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_edab1478-6055-4a29-aa01-1fe4426e6ff2.png' class='img-responsive'></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6'><div class='lws-homesection-body'>Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauí em 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire. Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauí em 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire.
Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauíem 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire.
Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauíem 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire.</div></div></div></div></div></section></div>

    <div id="GroupList1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div data-iw-group="group1">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_6310756a-7f23-4ba3-bedb-2b317c786ed3.png); background-size: cover" data-iw-bg="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_6310756a-7f23-4ba3-bedb-2b317c786ed3.png" data-iw-image="image_group1"  data-iw-version="medium" class="area-img"> </div>
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group1">Projetos</h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group1"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group1" class=" btn btn-primary" href="categories/projetos" role="button">Saiba mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div data-iw-group="group2">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_b665fc4e-f95d-4b91-9dea-138d5b287022.png); background-size: cover" data-iw-bg="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_b665fc4e-f95d-4b91-9dea-138d5b287022.png" data-iw-image="image_group2" data-iw-version="medium" class="area-img"> </div>
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group2">Biografia</h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group2"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group2" class=" btn btn-primary" href="biografia" role="button">Saiba mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div data-iw-group="group3">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_08c91774-9593-498f-b984-e4ac21991226.png); background-size: cover" data-iw-bg="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_08c91774-9593-498f-b984-e4ac21991226.png" data-iw-image="image_group3" data-iw-version="medium" class="area-img"> </div>
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group3">Fotos</h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group3"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group3" class=" btn btn-primary" href="categories/fotos" role="button">Saiba mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><section data-section-area='V20'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='V20' data-section-id='a40ab6b2-e909-4021-99b5-ac1ebde763d7'><h2 class='lws-homesection-title'>Notícias destaque</h2><div class='lws-homesection-resource-list'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'><div class='lws-homesection-wrapper-item'><div role='img' aria-label='' class='resource-list-post-thumbnail' style='background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_dc88125b-b8f3-4455-bcbc-de7d9d0720ca.jpg);background-size:cover'></div><h4 class='resource-list-title'>Fábio Abreu troca PTB pelo PR e tenta reeleição a deputado federal</h4><div class='resource-list-excerpt'>No evento de filiação ao PR, Fábio Abreu anunciou sua pré-candidatura a deputado federal e afirmou que está preparado para disputar a reeleição. O ...</div><a href='/posts/fabio-abreu-troca-ptb-pelo-pr-e-tenta-reeleicao-a-deputado-federal' class='btn btn-primary'>Veja mais</a></div></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'><div class='lws-homesection-wrapper-item'><div role='img' aria-label='' class='resource-list-post-thumbnail' style='background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_d445acdc-1a7f-4b75-a96c-76f3e0cf67d3.jpg);background-size:cover'></div><h4 class='resource-list-title'>Antes de entregar cargo, Fábio Abreu apresenta Plano de Segurança</h4><div class='resource-list-excerpt'>
O documento traça uma linha de trabalho para o setor pelos próximoa s20 anos e prevê investimentos que começam com um empréstimo junto ao BNDES p...</div><a href='/posts/antes-de-entregar-cargo-fabio-abreu-apresenta-plano-de-seguranca' class='btn btn-primary'>Veja mais</a></div></div><div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg"></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'><div class='lws-homesection-wrapper-item'><div role='img' aria-label='' class='resource-list-post-thumbnail' style='background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_56e67980-ecd2-444e-a0d9-e2c8a8735420.jpg);background-size:cover'></div><h4 class='resource-list-title'>Fábio Abreu destaca falta de atenção a segurança pública</h4><div class='resource-list-excerpt'>
Em entrevista ao Acorda Piauí, o deputado federal Fábio Abreu (PR), destacou que, enquanto a falta de segurança pública é um dos problemas mais a...</div><a href='/posts/fabio-abreu-destaca-falta-de-atencao-a-seguranca-publica' class='btn btn-primary'>Veja mais</a></div></div><div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12 col-lg-12"></div></div></div></div></section></div>

    <div id="GroupList2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="GL2-item" data-iw-group="group4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group4" class="featurette-heading"></h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group4" class="lead"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group4" class="hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif); background-size: cover" data-iw-image="image_group4" data-iw-version="medium"data-iw-bg="/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif" class="imagem-topicos"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="GL2-item" data-iw-group="group5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group5" class="featurette-heading"></h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group5" class="lead"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group5" class="hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif); background-size: cover" data-iw-image="image_group5" data-iw-version="medium"data-iw-bg="/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif" class="imagem-topicos"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="GL2-item" data-iw-group="group6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group6" class="featurette-heading"></h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group6" class="lead"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group6" class="hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif); background-size: cover" data-iw-image="image_group6" data-iw-version="medium"data-iw-bg="/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif" class="imagem-topicos"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><section data-section-area='V30'></section></div>
</div>

<footer id="MainFooter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="lws-home-sections-footer">
            <div class="lws-1-col-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><section data-section-area='F10'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='F10' data-section-id='f97be27b-c0e9-4229-b584-64ee920ef08a'><img src='https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/original_3939ae3f-43d1-4f63-a724-741c5ae11f47.png' class='img-responsive'></div></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-2-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F20'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F30'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-4-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F40'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F50'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F60'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F70'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <ul class="contacts_footer list-inline">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>

                <p>© 2018 - Fábio Abreu</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="lws-home-sections-footer">
            <div class="lws-1-col-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><section data-section-area='F80'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='F80' data-section-id='76c13c4e-249f-4cac-b9ae-e2a56220e80c'><div class='lws-homesection-body'>Todos os direitos reservados.
</div></div></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-2-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F90'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F100'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-4-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F110'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F120'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F130'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F140'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>


    <script src="/assets/site-fd70af901fb20b8029f75be40e0f5ff5848d5415b704279fd88ad5bc9c0ec4ec.js"></script>

    <script src="/assets/default/js/main-efff309d3722bafb3f5fa5a2092f366e799cac0d724996ca31c7e52b408475ec.js"></script>




        <div id="side-social-networks-loguei" role="group" class="list-unstyled btn-group-vertical">
    </div>



    <aside id="AVS-ContactButtons" class="force-neg-right">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">



    </ul>
</aside>

<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#AVS-ContactButtons ul li a span').css({
            right: '-200px'
        });
    }, 4000);
</script>



    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '1982872918652221',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.11'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.onload = function() { fbAsyncInit(); }
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=1982872918652221';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var NEWSLETTER_URL = '/fabio-abreu-1/newsletters';

        var DEFAULT_ADDRESS = '';

        $('.iw-contact-form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();var f = $(this);$.ajax({
                url:'/contact/fabio-abreu-1?authenticity_token=PEYv9F1ndM5YEDywj8kpZEV5LBE4n7ifIIRuXvvtMk1EEytCR8kGwr6DuarKQhgTtiscTD7xc9prc7e12oOlpg%3D%3D',
                type:'POST',data:f.serialize(),success:function(){
                    var redir = $('#iw_redir_loguei_cf').length;
                    if (redir == 0) {alert('Email enviado com sucesso');f[0].reset();} else {
                        var to = $('#iw_redir_loguei_cf').val(); window.location=to;
                    }
                },error:function(){alert('Erro ao enviar email');}
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS code in moment:

```
#menu-main li:last-child{
  margin-left: 376px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 1px; 
}

#menu-main li:last-child{
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius: 66px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:1px 22px;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: On the "Entre em contato" button. I want to center the word inside the rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (After commenting back and forth):

To get the text centered and to have the hover effect cover the whole inside of the button, while keeping the same width of the button, change the css like this:

Current:

```
#menu-main li:last-child a {
    padding: 7px 19px 5px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-border: 42px;
}

#menu-main li:last-child {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 66px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-align: center justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Change to (Remove padding on button and text, put border radius on text, set text width and height to the same as the button, and I also deleted stuff that wasn't doing anything/was incorrectly written)

NEW NEW:(Add `width: 100%` to navbar and a media query for `float: right` to button on screens of `768px` and up):

```
#menu-main {
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-main li:last-child a {
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 66px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-main li:last-child {
    border-radius: 66px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 175px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #menu-main li:last-child {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

http://res.cloudinary.com/maxmaxs5/image/upload/v1533423313/Test.png

Glad to help!

---

I believe you are wanting to change the padding value on this section?:

```
#menu-main li:last-child{
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius: 66px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    //padding:1px 22px;
    padding:1px 10px;
}
```

You might want to fiddle with the second pixel value till it gets what you want but 10px might be it.. `padding:1px 10px;`

When setting `padding`, the first value is top/bottom, and the second is left/right. So adjusting the second value will change how much padding the sides of the text get.

Hopefully this helps, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Kieran, this problem has been resolved, the name is centralized. What bothers me now is that the space inside the rectangle is too large, even touching the edges of the menu. Can you help me solve it?

Comment: This is the problem: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/544/955/thumb/Capturar.PNG?1533360551

Comment: Did Morteza fix it up for you or are you still having issues? I would still say the too much space was likely from too much padding, or height, or line-height?

Comment: Morteza helped me solve this issue of button framing. What gets me the wits now is exactly the question of the button not being correctly filled. I'll attach the image link here to see if you understand me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8roPY.png

Comment: If I am getting you right, that looks like you have put a `background-color: red` on the text within the button, and that you still have to much padding left/right on the button itself. To fix the red box try changing it to `background-color: transparent` (Unless you were just using the red to show that it overlaps). The fact that the text is going over the top and bottom of the button is likely due to too much line-height on the text, which then overflows the fixed height of the button. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Notice that I was able to decrease the width of the internal paddings of the button, now I would like it to be leased to the white border, do you know how I can do that? www.fabioabreupi.com.br

Comment: I assume by "leased to the white border", that you want to have the on hover red background cover the entire inside of the button?

Comment: Check the updated post now, that should be it. Let me know if there is more you need or if that is the accepted answer?

Comment: Oh my god, Kieran. You really saved me. Thank you very much.

Comment: But in the matter of responsiveness, the button in question gets totally out of the listing. I'll leave a picture attached so you can watch. Is there any code I can implement to align it with others? https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/545/753/thumb/122.PNG?1533433252

Comment: I did notice that as well. That comes from the `margin-left: 376px` that you have on it. If you change that down to `margin-left: 20px` and change width down to `width: 175px` as well as adding a `margin-bottom: 5px`, that should allow all different screen sizes to see it properly. I updated the CSS in the post. If this works please choose an accepted answer

Comment: And you are very welcome, I am glad to help someone else do good work and learn :)

Comment: What is new is the customer who is farthest from others. I was able to do this using margin-left: 376px but it was not right on the responsive.

Comment: By this I am assuming you want to have the button always on the far right side of the navbar exact mobile? If so, you need to add a media query to listen for different screen sizes. That is how the navbar is readjusting when you change the width of your screen. You want to add a `width: 100%` to the navbar and add the changes I put in the EDIT section still. After that, you need to add a media query for screens of size `768px` and up to put a `float: right` on the button. Check my EDIT section again for the new stuff and let me know. Also, can you give me your email so we can chat more easily?

Comment: Yes, please contact me at: pedrodbt8@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

you something wrong not need to writing rule twice:

```
#menu-main li:last-child{
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #none;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius:1px;
    border-radius: 66px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:1px 22px;
}
```

you can use:

```
button{
 text-align:center
}
```

or use display flex added to wrapper element the centralise children element:

```
div{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: The problem now is to keep the text centered inside the box, I'm not getting any way: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/544/955/thumb/Capturar.PNG?1533360551

Comment: you can use display flex for button.

Comment: I'm already using it. And so it has not yet been centered in the rectangle. I am getting crazy. hahah

Comment: Morteza, thank you. 
I was applying the display flex incorrectly, so it was not solved. I apologize for my ignorance as a beginner. Thanks for the help, my friend